# python global variable/java python translate

Tags: java, python

I am new to python and start to convert a piece of Java code into python.

I am taking advice:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/ to imitate Java static block in python

```
class ConfigurationManager:
    try:
        readIn = open('C:/Users/george/Desktop/hello.txt','r')
        # readIn = open('./resources/my.properties','r')
    except Exception as e:
        print('except:',e)
    finally:
        if readIn:
            readIn.close()
    def read(self):
        print(readIn.read())


con = ConfigurationManager()
con.read()
```

and got :

> D:\Python27\python.exe D:/laotang/session/conf/ConfigurationManager.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/laotang/session/conf/ConfigurationManager.py", line 18, in
>   
>       con.read()   File "D:/laotang/session/conf/ConfigurationManager.py", line 14, in read
>       print(readIn.read()) NameError: global name 'readIn' is not defined

the original Java code：

```
static {
        try {
            InputStream in = ConfigurationManager.class
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my.properties"); 

            prop.load(in);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
```

someone please kindly fix it,thanks

Comment: I personally find geeksforgeeks.org being terrible at explaining stuff and their code contains some very bad practices, at least for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Python is mainly a scripting language unlike Java. Java is a Object Oriented Language. So There are some differentiations when coneverting from java code to python code. But python also supports class concept. In your case the working code is,

```
class ConfigurationManager:

    def read(self):
        try:
            readIn = open('C:/Users/george/Desktop/hello.txt', 'r')
            # readIn = open('./resources/my.properties','r')
            print(readIn.read())
        except Exception as e:
             print('except:', e)
        finally:
            if readIn:
                readIn.close()


con = ConfigurationManager()
con.read()
```

But this is not the best python code for your requirement. My opinion is first of all you should learn python basics instead of converting java code into python.